# How to get releases information from github using php-curl (with credentials)?

Tags: php, curl, github, github-api

I am able fetch github release details using curl but I want to do this using php.

The command I use in curl is the following:

```
curl -u user.ca:password -X GET https://api.github.com/repos/xyz/abc/releases
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The php equivalent of the `-u` option is `CURLOPT_USERPWD`.

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, 'user.ca:password');
```

In the end you will have something like this:

```
$ch = curl_init(); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://api.github.com/repos/xyz/abc/releases"); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, 'user.ca:password');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT,'Awesome-Octocat-App');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
$fetch = curl_exec($ch); 
curl_close($ch);
```

Comment: and how to print output ?

I tried print $fetch and got

Request forbidden by administrative rules. Please make sure your request has a User-Agent header (http://developer.github.com/v3/#user-agent-required). Check https://developer.github.com for other possible causes.

Comment: added user-agent, `CURLOPT_USERAGENT`

Comment: can you please help with how I can add its output to a file

Comment: `file_put_contents('filename', $fetch);`, doc [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php)